# Parsing large XML files(Airspace, Point and Route in AIXM 5.1) with xlinks using Jaxb taking long time

Tags: xml, jaxb, xlink, jxpath

I am trying to parse an AIXM5.1 xml file of size >50 MB using JAXB. I am able to unmarshal this xml within a minute itself. But, when I try to iterate through the java object and fetching values of the fields in XML it is taking huge time.
After analyzing I found that the xml has xlinks which internally refer to an xml fragment with in the same xml, like there are around **40000 xlink references** are there. So everytime for finding the specific xml fragment which is referred in xlink I am trying to iterate through the whole object. which is taking time.

Sample xml fragment is as below

```
<aixm:geometryComponent>
<aixm:AirspaceGeometryComponent gml:id="ID_2903_1384156119164_17492"><aixm:operation>BASE</aixm:operation>
<aixm:theAirspaceVolume>
<aixm:AirspaceVolume gml:id="ID_2903_1384156119164_17493">
<aixm:upperLimit uom="FL">30</aixm:upperLimit><aixm:upperLimitReference>STD</aixm:upperLimitReference>
<aixm:lowerLimit uom="FT">GND</aixm:lowerLimit><aixm:lowerLimitReference>MSL</aixm:lowerLimitReference>
<aixm:contributorAirspace>
<aixm:AirspaceVolumeDependency gml:id="ID_2903_1384156119164_17494"><aixm:dependency>HORZ_PROJECTION</aixm:dependency>
**<aixm:theAirspace xlink:href="urn:uuid:1c49634e-62ea-4319-bf80-23f3912cef8e">**</aixm:theAirspace>
</aixm:AirspaceVolumeDependency>
</aixm:contributorAirspace>
</aixm:AirspaceVolume>
</aixm:theAirspaceVolume>
</aixm:AirspaceGeometryComponent>
</aixm:geometryComponent>
```

If you observe  element has a *xlink:href attribute it has uuid value* through this uuid I have to find out the Airspace xml fragment with the matching uuid. Like this there are 40000+ references exist in the xml.

When I googled to resolve xlinks through JAXB I found that JXPath i an alternative. But I could not find the examples pertaining to JXPath with inherited classes.

Please guide me if anybody worked on it or suggest me any other technologies.

Looking forward for your help..